# What is funny about "Can I have a chocolate donut and a bottle of beer"?

Tags: plot-explanation, dialogue, scarecrow

In [Scarecrow](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0070643/combined) (1973), what is funny about the line "Can I have a chocolate donut and a bottle of beer"?

Comment: According to imdb and some other sites the quote is "Gimme a chocolate donut and a bottle of beer." However, on script sites it the one that is currently in the question. Hopefully this benefits the search for an answer.

Comment: Also here is an sourceless explanation of why Pacino is laughing:
http://silverscreenoasis.com/oasis3/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=4898&start=15

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Donuts are mostly thought of as breakfast food, while beer is usually associated with an afternoon/evening activity.  Besides, at the time there were no micro-breweries offering [Chocolate Donut Beer](https://www.google.com/search?q=chocolate%20donut%20beer&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=sb); the combination of flavors was pretty offbeat.

Comment: Donuts for breakfast... you Americans are weird! :-p

Answer (score 1):

Simply and without going into much complexity, Does a combination of Doughnuts and Beers look normal to you? I think not. That's whats funny about it.

Comment: This is a perfectly good answer to the question.

Comment: No, it really doesn't provide an answer. It's more of an opinion and without some kind of explanation or reasoning other than, "It's not a normal request," it's more a comment if anything.

Comment: This is like saying "its funny cuz its funny"

Comment: Well, the person who asked this question doesn't understand whether it is normal to have Doughnuts and Beers for breakfast. We just have to convince him that its not. Do you want to convince him otherwise?

Comment: And I believe that only others' opinions can convince him. If you are battling with me or anyone else on this you're just ruining a good movie for our pal.